# Loop while and if statement priorities

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I've created this simple class, because i've just realised, I don't understand how if statements work inside a while loop. I seem not to understand how are they prioritize??

Why is this code getting an infinite loop I don't get?? Could you explain ?

```
package sam;
public class Sam {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean actif = true;
        boolean wake = false;
        while(actif==true ){
            System.out.println("Statut :"+actif);

            if(actif && wake){
                System.out.println("Actif :"+actif);
                System.out.println("Wake :"+wake);
                if(wake){
                    System.out.println("Wake est activé");
                }   
                if(actif){
                    actif=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that if I move that down below as a first condition, the loop is broken properly:

```
  if(actif){
            actif=false;
        }
```

Could you enlighten me on that?

Comment: The language that you're using should always be one of your tags. And tags shouldn't also appear in titles. Finally, when posting code, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button so that it's formatted as code properly. (And, together with the language tag, we then get syntax highlighting)

Comment: Testing `actif` inside a loop that only executes if `actif` is `true` and at a place where it hasn't been changed since the outer test is completely pointless.

Comment: Don’t write `while(actif==true )` as `while(actif)` says everything already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have not ended your if statement:

```
if(actif && wake){
           System.out.println("Actif :"+actif);
           System.out.println("Wake :"+wake);
        if(wake){
            System.out.println("Wake est activé");
        }   
        if(actif){
            actif=false;
        }

        }
```

You are setting actif = false inside this if statement which never gets executed.

```
ideally it should be : 
if(actif && wake){
           System.out.println("Actif :"+actif);
           System.out.println("Wake :"+wake);
}
        if(wake){
            System.out.println("Wake est activé");
        }   
        if(actif){
            actif=false;
        }
```

Comment: there is no such thing as an "if loop"

Comment: Changed to if statement

Answer (score 1):

Correctly indenting your code will show immediately why actif is never set to false.

`wake` starts at false, so the first if condition is never true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explaination indicating why your code will be in infinite loop.

In your code, you declared 2 variables as follows:

```
 boolean actif = true;
 boolean wake = false;
```

if-condition in while-loop **`if (actif && wake) {`**, it always be **false**,

Then the following code will never be executed.

```
    if(actif){
        actif=false;
    }
```

So, `actif` will always **true**.

As a result, the while-loop condition **while(actif==true ){** will always be true. and the infinite loop appears.

Reorganize your thoughts to make some change to set actif as false in some place, to stop the infinite loop. Go ahead. :)

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your example, the if condition,

`if(actif){
            actif=false;
        }`

is inside another if condition

```
if(actif && wake){
       System.out.println("Actif :"+actif);
       System.out.println("Wake :"+wake);
    if(wake){
        System.out.println("Wake est activé");
    }   
    **if(actif){
        actif=false;**
    }

    }
```

As you have mentioned `boolean wake = false;`befor the while loop, Wake is always `false`, so never it will go to the `above if conditonal statements`, so always `actif=true` as mentioned before the while loop. thats the reason the code getting an infinite loop.

hope you got.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, when it comes inside the while loop it checks the first if condition

```
if(actif && wake)
```

which evaluates to false and since everything else is inside this if block that means nothing else is executed and it goes back to the second iteration of while loop. Again the same thing happens and because of the first if loop, that again evaluates to false, the loop goes into infinite recursion. You have to manipulate either one of the flags, i.e. actif/wake to make the if loop evaluate to true or else the loop will never break.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if condition -- if(actif && wake) --  in the while loop contains

```
if(actif){
   actif=false;
}
```

And because you set wake to false in the beginning this code gets never executed because aktif && wake is false.
If affects als code inside the {} after it.
See also:
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)